# R ROI Optimization: Constraints by Group

Tags: r, optimization, constraints

I am writing a supply chain optimization in R using the `ROI` package, aiming to minimize costs of buying a product across different stores, suppliers and months.

Here is simplified example data, with just 2 stores/suppliers/months:

`Data <- data.frame(Store = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),Supplier = c("A","A","B","B","A","A","B","B"),Month = c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2),Cost = c(3,4,2,5,3,4,2,5),Order_Quantity = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)`

`Forecast <- data.frame(Store = c(1,2), Forecast = c(1000,2000))`

When I begin to write the optimization, I immediately find a problem setting constraints:

`Opt <- OP(objective = L_objective(Data$Cost),L_constraint(...`

I need to require that each store order at least as much as it's demand forecast, or the minimal-cost solution would be to not order anything.

In the ROI documentation example, constraints are applied to each individual decision point:

`lp <- OP(objective = c(2, 4, 3), L_constraint(L = matrix(c(3, + 2, 1, 4, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2), nrow = 3), dir = c("<=", "<=", "<="), + rhs = c(60, 40, 80)), maximum = TRUE)`

My constraint is not on each order decision point (a "store-supplier-month"), but a group of these.  The order quantity of the store overall (the first 4 rows) must sum to at least the demand forecast at that store.  I'm unsure what the syntax would look like for this.

I found documentation on a `group_constraint` (link at the bottom) which seems to allow me to select some of the decision points for a constraint, but I do not see how to sum them or consider them as a group.

There are other group constraints I will need to write, such as each supplier having a finite capacity, so the order quantity of rows 1,2,5,6 in my example data must sum to no more than that capacity.

**Does anyone have experience writing "group constraints" like this for an optimization problem, or have clearer examples to share?**  I would be happy to reorganize my data, or use a different R optimization package than ROI if it makes writing these kinds of constraints easier.  Thank you so much for your help.

Link 1: http://roi.r-forge.r-project.org/use_case_portfolio_optimization.html#example_1:_maximize_expected_return_subject_to_budget_normalization_and_group_constraints

Comment: I would suggest to first develop a proper formulated mathematical model. After you have stated that, selected the right solver (and modeling tool) is easier, and also coding the problem up is easier. I suspect there is nothing difficult about your "group constraints" (we never call them like that).

Comment: What would you call a constraint that applies to a group of variables (Store 1, or x1 to x4 in my example data summing to >= demand forecast F)?

Comment: They don't have a name as such. Almost all constraints are dealing with subsets of variables (and almost no constraints deal with all variables). We would name them more functionally, e.g. "capacity constraints".

Comment: OK, thank you for that.  All of my planned constraints can be made by subsetting the data in 3 ways (by store, supplier, or time period, or a combination of these).  Would you recommend coding all constraints explicitly ( SUM(x1:x4) >= F1, SUM(x5:8) >= F2, etc.), or do you know of functionality to sum according to a criterion (such as store)?  Do you have experience personally with ROI, or another R optimization package that leverages 'functional' constraints such as summation by criteria?

Comment: I have used ROI only for toy problems as it is not suited for the models I encounter during work.